# How does one refer to a file in a maven dependency?

Tags: maven, fabric8

**Context**

I am using the maven plugin [Fabric8](http://dmp.fabric8.io/#simple-dockerfile-build) to build a docker container during my integration tests. One of my maven dependencies has a Dockerfile in its src/main/resources folder.

I would like to refer to that Dockerfile in the build phase of the plugin's image configuration.

In Intellij I can see the Dockerfile in the External Libraries section.

```
Maven: com.example.project:myartifact:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  myartifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    container-dir
      Dockerfile
```

**Question**

How do I refer to a file in an External Library / Maven Dependency?

In other words, what is the relative path to a mvn project's dependency files?

**Other Info**

Where it is in the code:

```
<configuration>
    <images>
        <image>
            <alias>database</alias>
            <name>container-name</name>
            <build>
                <dockerFileDir>?????</dockerFileDir>
            </build>
```

I have seen this question: [Reading a resource file from within jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar) but this only answer the question for how to refer to the file within Java but not with Maven itself.

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies are JARs. JARs are ZIPs. They are resolved from the local Maven repository (`${user.home}/.m2/repository` by default in [`settings.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html))(and downloaded from a remote repository before if there is such and if one isn't in the local repository yet). So, you can't access files in them just by a (relative or absolute) path directly.

If this is a dependency you create yourself (you mention `src/main/resources` of it) the relative path depends on your directory structure, e.g.:

```text
+- dependency
|  +- src/main/resources
|     +- Dockerfile
+- project
   + pom.xml
```

From `project`'s view it would be `../dependency/src/main/resources/Dockerfile` then, IF you run `mvn ...` from within `/project`. If you run it from an other location with `.../not-project $ mvn -f /path/to/project/pom.xml ...` you're out of luck with this.

And if, for instance, someone checks out `project` but not `dependency` (since the latter is resolved from a repository anyway) (s)he is completely out of luck.

So, I don't recommend this since relying on local paths external to a project is not too safe. The safer and Maven way is to place this resource in `project/src/main/resources` (this dir's name is not just by chance ;).

OTOH, I understand to keep `Dockerfile` in its `dependency` project since that's were it belongs to for its development.

To make it availble to `project` you can use [`maven-dependency-plugin:unpack`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) with its [Usage page section](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html#dependency:unpack) (which is a bit confusing concerning `<executions>` and `<configuration>`):

> Goal that retrieves a list of artifacts from the repository and unpacks them in a defined location.